# Autosys - How to restart job from the middle of Box job

Tags: autosys

There are 5 jobs inside a Main Box job like this

```
MainBox
Job1 -> Job2 -> Job3 -> Job4 -> Job5
```

job2 is dependent on Job1, Job3 is dependent on Job2 and so on.

The dependency is implemented with condition attribute. For instance, Job2 has condtion: success(Job1).

On starting the MainBox, jobs will run in sequence. Suppose Job3 got failed. Now, how to re-start jobs inside MainBox from the failed Job3?

If I manually force start Job3 then it runs but the dependent Job4 does not get started after the success of Job3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in the setup you have mentioned, if any of the job fails, the Box will fail and downstream jobs will go to inactive state if condition is **"box_terminator: y"** set for the jobs. In this case you will have to manually complete the downstream by force starting each as conditions will not work as the Box itself is failed.

In order to achieve what you need to do a little tweak in jobs, make **"box_terminator: n"**. Then the on any job's failure, the Box will stay in running state and the downstream jobs will stay in activated state waiting for failed job to be success. You can the either mark the failed job as success to skip its run or force start to completion, since the box is still in running state, the dependencies will work for each jobs within it.

But be sure to include **"trem_runtime:** *value_in_minutes* **"** for the Box, so that box fails after some time if failed job is unattended, else box will run indefinitely.

I think this should do.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve your requirement through below steps. Its an alternative method,

Step 1: Put ON_HOLD job1 and job2 which are ran and completed successfully.
Step 2: Terminate the box job if it is in running state.
Step 3: Start the box job.
step 4: Mark the job1 and job2 to success state from ON_HOLD state.
step 5: Check the status of the Box job and you can see that the job sequence start running from job3.

Regards,
Kaliraja.

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to restart the failed job without impacting the success job/s and for the remaining ACTIVE/INACTIVE jobs to run automatically (since it's dependent on the failed job), you need to use the ON_ICE feature of autosys. ON_ICE is just like a SUCCESS status. If your job is ON_ICE, Autosys will read this as SUCCESS and it will not be triggered again. Hence, since your dependency of job3 is the SU of job2, your job3 will run automatically once you've force started your main BOX (skipping to run the job1 and job2 considering they are already in ON_ICE status). Below are the steps you can perform:

1. If your main box is still in RU status, force STOP your main box.
2. ON_ICE your job1 and job2.
3. FORCE START your main box.
4. Once box already force started, your job3 will automatically run.
5. Once your job3 already turned to SU, your job4 will run immediately.
6. Once job4 already completed its run, your main box should turn to SU since your job1 and job2 are in ON_ICE state and your job3 and job4 are in SU state.
7. You can now set OFF_ICE the jobs job1 and job2 so as in the next schedule run of the main box, these jobs will be kicked off.

Note: The start and end run of the job1 and job2 should not change. The start and end run of your main box, job3, and job4 should have the updated time.